# Does favoriting questions degrade gracefully for anyone else (e.g. via a phone's browser, or with JavaScript turned off)?

Tags: support, bookmarks, javascript, mobile-web

I browse Stack Overflow via a phone, using a not-amazingly-JavaScript-friendly browser.  I have low expectations as a result of the tool I'm using, but there are two options that seem essential:

- reading through questions and answers (status: success)
- saving interesting questions for later interaction on a more capable browser by favoriting them (status: failure)

Is it just me/my browser, or is that basic functionality that doesn't degrade gracefully without JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Favoriting requires JavaScript.

Is there any reason you can't bookmark on your device? That'd be the lowest tech simple way to get that done...

Comment: bookmarking would not let him come back to the quesions on his PC,  ("later interaction on a more capable browser")

Comment: @Ian, it would, it'd just take more legwork. Fortunately, the OP is already expecting to have to do some legwork.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have any way to get bookmarks -off- the phone other than editing the bookmark and retyping out the url in a desktop browser, and at that point I'm almost at the same level as just writing the url down on a piece of notepaper and retyping it out in a desktop browser.

Comment: Seems unfortunate that the favoriting link (which does actually show up as text without javascript, just doesn't do anything) doesn't have a js-less fallback method.  Should I try opening a feature-request question for that or something?

Comment: @tchal I favor editing this question to turn it into a feature-request

Comment: I decided to upgrade my device in the end!

Comment: @tchal an excellent choice!