# Privilege creation: answering and upvoting without JavaScript, targets vision impaired people

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, javascript, accessibility, noscript

I would like the creation of the privilege to answer and upvote, logged in, but without JavaScript.

Set it at as high as 1000 points, if you fear robots. You may even take, for example, 200 points to people activating that privilege. Vision impaired people, like me, would be happy even at such a price.

The objective is allow for more participation from security-aware people, and also from vision impaired (me) and blind people. The question *[What are the pros and cons of supporting anonymous participation on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208813/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-supporting-anonymous-participation-in-stackexchang)* even asks for anonymous answering, so my request seems to be more reasonable.

Some people browse without JavaScript following recommendations[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70438/does-favoriting-questions-degrade-gracefully-for-anyone-else-e-g-via-a-phones), others are forced to do so [because of their device](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70438/does-favoriting-questions-degrade-gracefully-for-anyone-else-e-g-via-a-phones) or because of one of their configuration settings not closely related[2].

[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70438/does-favoriting-questions-degrade-gracefully-for-anyone-else-e-g-via-a-phones)

- *[Allow privileges links to be clicked without JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208667/allow-privileges-links-to-be-clicked-without-javascript)*
- *[The stackexchange.com 'sites' page doesn't work without JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128385/the-stackexchange-com-sites-page-doesnt-work-without-javascript)*
- http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2012/06/ghostery.html

[2]

- *["Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117851/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-which-is-block/117852#117852)*
- *[I can't add comments or answer questions (JavaScript enabled)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72417/i-cant-add-comments-or-answer-questions-javascript-enabled)*
- *[External JavaScript code failed to load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96373/external-javascript-code-failed-to-load)*

Comment: Java and javascript are completely different things. You've confused them twice here.

Comment: It is likely a very small percentage of people who access SO do so without JS, so I'm not sure if the overhead in allowing for this feature has enough of a benefit to do. For instance for UK site gov.uk [only 1.1% of users didn't receive JS](http://digital.cabinetoffice.gov.uk/2013/10/21/how-many-people-are-missing-out-on-javascript-enhancement/), and 0.2% of those users had intentionally disabled it (noScript on using browsers that don't use JScript)- suggesting intentional use of NoScript is very low (OK, SO users are likely different to gov.uk, but I don't know how different).

Comment: It's like saying 'only x percent if people is blind so it's not worth the effort'. OP quotes real practical issues no stats are going to help him with.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, changing the site so it *can* be used without JavaScript is no small feat. It would take a long time. For what benefit?

Second - privileges are there as things you can *do* on the site that you couldn't before - just enabling no-JavaScript browsing is not in-line with that. It doesn't give you something you any additional action on the site that you couldn't do before.

Comment: Now, I can provide my password, but then it results in 404 on https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login/submit so I understand that.

Comment: There are many of us that do not have JavaScript enabled and browse the web.  Most of us who do have it disabled turn it off due to security concerns and this is often something that is mandated as policy at our workplace so not much choice there on our part.  Others disable it for speed, no ads, etc..  I often browse using a text only browser like links, w3m, or elinks so no love there either.  Making the site work without JS would bring benefits to those in the same boat.

Comment: @unclejamil - unfortunately, that's not something we will be doing. From the very start of the site, JavaScript has been required, and its usage has only increased since. It will take years for us to make it fully work without JS.

Comment: @Oded thanks for caring enough to answer. I am vision impaired, but I am fortunate enough to be able to use firefox. What about blind people ? This is about accessibility.

Comment: @user2987828 - I am no longer working for Stack Exchange, so not something I can respond to anymore.

Comment: I guess OP requests that it would be a privilege because he thinks that preventing spam is one of the reasons JS is required.

Comment: @StijndeWitt [Since less than two months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-1-2018/307691#comment1001011_307691), it is possible to edit posts without any javascript, in lynx browser. Posting [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50099739/2987828) required me to re-open [the SE page](httNOGREPps://stackoverflow.com/nocaptcha?s=ed73fab1-bd72-dfb4-a683-2e0881779772) that contains Google's [ReCaptcha iframe](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=fm6Lzf4SAAAAAEBXEsm) in a incognito firefox window where I was logged in the SE site.

Comment: This time I did not have to solve any captcha, just to reopen the said link in firefox.